# Twig use statement fails with "with ... as" declarations

Tags: twig

I have twig.js 0.8.2. When I try to use the "use" statement like here:

```
{% use "../../base/hello.twig " %}
```

The file is imported without any problem, but if hello.twig has at least one block having the same name of the current one, I want to use this instead:

```
{% use "../../base/hello.twig " with content as parent-content %}
```

My node.js server cast an error:

```
TwigException: Twig.expression.type.variable cannot follow a
Twig.expression.type.string at template:36 near 'with...'
Error parsing twig template views/parkers/hpi-check/nmr-help.twig:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Note that I am using twig.js instead of php twig

Answer (score 0):

im pretty sure that its because you have a minus in your variable name, try change it to a underscore

Comment: I have tried to remove it, but I still got the same error.

Comment: Okay, at least in the php twig your not allowed to use minus/dash